# Como pedir argumentos BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script

### Problema

Buenas estoy tratando de realizar un script en bash, necesito pasar dos argumentos al script en este caso ruta y ID de la política, el problema me viene cuando ejecuto el script con la siguiente línea de comando: `./allowedURLs -f ruta -i testID` la salida me printea la ruta pero el ID nunca lo coge he probado a ejecutarlo con solo el ID de argumento y tampoco lo muestra por pantalla.

### Fragmento del :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Parsing arguments
while getopts 'if:' OPTION; do
    case "${OPTION}" in
        i) 
            echo "id"
            policy_id=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        f)
            echo "file"
            input_file=${OPTARG}
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "$# non arguments were passed"

echo "ID: $policy_id";
echo "Input file: ${input_file}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getoptions estaba mal definida para distintos argumentos hay que separarlos con `:`  y en el caso de tu echo del ID faltaba mostrarlo de manera correcta mediante

```
echo "ID:${policy_id}";
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#Parsing arguments
while getopts 'i:f:' OPTION; do
    case "${OPTION}" in
        i) 
            policy_id=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        f)
            input_file=${OPTARG}
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

echo "ID: ${policy_id}";
echo "Input file: ${input_file}";
```